# Is there a tool to check /etc/hosts.{allow,deny} syntax?

Tags: configuration, tcp-wrappers

I am looking for a command line tool that checks tcp_wrapper configuration file syntax to make sure daemon names are set right and things like that, check for spelling or syntax errors etc.

Comment: `tcp_wrappers` would probably complain if the syntax was wrong. Nobody can tell that the hostnames are misspelt though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to ftp://ftp.porcupine.org/pub/security/hints-and-tips.html:

> If tcpd access rules do not work as expected, run `tcpdchk -v` and see if its output matches your expectation. If that does not clear things up, please use the `tcpdmatch` command, report what it says, and also report what result you expected to get. Both commands come with the tcp wrapper source code.